# CActiveRecord Find By Attributes Where Field Is Null

Tags: mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord, cactiverecord

In Yii 1.1.*, how to find all data (via `CActiveRecord` implementation) where an attributes is `NULL`, kinda like:

```
Foo::model()->findAllByAttributes(['bar' => 'baz', 'qux' => [null, '']]);
```

> It **DOES NOT** work because it produces query: `WHERE (bar = 'baz') AND (qux IN (, ''))`

I want to find all `Foo` records `where`:

- `"bar"` field equals with `"baz"`
- `AND` `qux` field `IS NULL` or equals with empty string

I can do it with **`findAll`**, but how about if I want to use **`findAllByAttributes`** method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$cityModel = Cities::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("citny_name"=>"d"), "state_id IS NULL OR state_id = ''");
```

The executed query:

```
SELECT * FROM `cities` `t` WHERE `t`.`citny_name`=:yp0 AND
(state_id IS NULL OR state_id = ''). Bound with :yp0='d'
```

Comment: The executed query explains so many things. Thanks you, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the condition for `quz` as an additional parameter into `findAllByAttributes`:

```
Foo::model()->findAllByAttributes(['bar' => 'baz'], "quz IS NULL OR quz = ''")
```

You can't use `IN` with `null` values unless you replace `CDbCommandBuilder` with your own implementation. `CActiveRecord::findAllByAttributes` calls [`CDbCommandBuilder::createColumnCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommandBuilder#createColumnCriteria-detail) which in turn calls [`CDbCommandBuilder::createInCondition`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommandBuilder#createInCondition-detail) if the column values are an array.

From the [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/db/schema/CDbCommandBuilder.php#L786) values are cast into the column type and quoted afterwards and passed through `implode` resulting in the `null` being treated as php's `null` not mysql's `null`:

```
foreach($values as &$value)
{
    $value=$column->typecast($value);
    if(is_string($value))
        $value=$db->quoteValue($value);
}
...
return $prefix.$column->rawName.' IN ('.implode(', ',$values).')';
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Your explanation is very clear.